# Remove space while doing array_agg

Tags: postgresql

How to trim the white spaces while doing array_agg. If you notice the activities row is giving the result with so many white spaces. Is there any way to remove those white spaces

```
select dev.id, dev.name, array_agg(da.event_type) activities from developers dev
JOIN (
   select event_type, developer_id from activities
) da ON da.developer_id = dev.id
group by dev.id;
```

Output

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id         | 4
name       | naveen                                            
activities | {"push                                              "}
-[ RECORD 2 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id         | 2
name       | shikhar                                           
activities | {"pull                                              ","push                                              ","delete                                            "}
-[ RECORD 3 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id         | 1
name       | aniket                                            
activities | {"push                                              ","pull                                              ","fork                                              ","push                                              ","push                                              "}
-[ RECORD 4 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id         | 3
name       | varun                                             
activities | {"fork                                              ","fork                                              ","push                                              "}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using trim

```
select dev.id, dev.name, array_agg(trim(da.event_type)) activities from developers dev
JOIN (
   select event_type, developer_id from activities
) da ON da.developer_id = dev.id
group by dev.id;
```